# Implementation of standard recycling rules

Tags: r

One nice feature of R which is related to its inherent vectorized nature is the recycling rule described in [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) in Section 2.2.

> Vectors occurring in the same expression need not all be of the same length. If they are not, the value of the expression is a vector with the same length as the longest vector which occurs in the expression. Shorter vectors in the expression are *recycled* as often as need be (perhaps fractionally) until they match the length of the longest vector. In particular a constant is simply repeated.

Most standard functions use this, but the code that does so is buried in the underlying C code.

Is there a canonical way to implement the standard recycling rules for a function entirely in R code? That is, given a function like

```
mock <- function(a, b, c) {
    # turn a, b, and c into appropriate recycled versions

    # do something with recycled a, b, and c in some appropriately vectorized way
}
```

where `a`, `b`, and `c` are vectors, possibly of different lengths and unknown types/classes, is there a canonical way to get a new set of vectors which are recycled according to the standard recycling rules? In particular, I can't assume that "do something" step will do the proper recycling itself, so I need to do it myself beforehand.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've used this in the past,

```
expand_args <- function(...){
  dots <- list(...)
  max_length <- max(sapply(dots, length))
  lapply(dots, rep, length.out = max_length)
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `lengths(dots)` instead of  `sapply(dots, length)` from R 3.2 on

Answer (score 9):

I'd likely use the `length.out` argument of `rep()` to do most of the real work.

Here's an example that creates a `better.data.frame()` function (it should really be called `"better".data.frame()`), which places no restrictions on the lengths of the vectors it's handed as arguments. In this case, I recycle all of the vectors to the length of the the longest one, but you can obviously adapt this to serve your own recycling needs!

```
better.data.frame <- function(...) {
    cols <- list(...)
    names(cols) <- sapply(as.list(match.call()), deparse)[-1]

    # Find the length of the longest vector
    # and then recycle all columns to that length.
    n <- max(lengths(cols))
    cols <- lapply(cols, rep, length.out = n)

    as.data.frame(cols)
}

# Try it out
a <- Sys.Date() + 0:9
b <- 1:3
c <- letters[1:4]

data.frame(a,b,c)
# Error in data.frame(a, b, c) : 
#   arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 3, 4

better.data.frame(a,b,c)
#             a b c
# 1  2012-02-17 1 a
# 2  2012-02-18 2 b
# 3  2012-02-19 3 c
# 4  2012-02-20 1 d
# 5  2012-02-21 2 a
# 6  2012-02-22 3 b
# 7  2012-02-23 1 c
# 8  2012-02-24 2 d
# 9  2012-02-25 3 a
# 10 2012-02-26 1 b
```

Comment: You could ammend your `n <-` to handle the case where the longest argument is not the first.  `n <- max(unlist(lapply(list(a,b,c),length),max)` and add an `a <- rep(a, length.out = n)`.

Comment: @Justin -- Thanks. I was just off doing that, and also generalizing the function to take an arbitrary number of arguments. If you (or anyone else) see a better way for me to pluck out the names of the supplied arguments from inside the function call, please let me know. That's just what I came up with on the fly...

Answer (score 2):

One short-and-dirty route for numerical arguments is to rely on cbind's automatic recycling. For example:

```
f.abc <- function(a,b,c) {

     df.abc <- as.data.frame( suppressWarnings( cbind(a=a, b=b, c=c) ) )

     #Then use, for example, with() to use a, b and c inside the data frame, 
     #or apply(df.abc,1, ...) 
}
```

It does rely heavily on there being no other legitimate cause for warnings, though.