# unconditional warnings when recycling

Tags: r

I'll start my question by reminding what "recycling" is, and for that, I will quote another user (re: Brian Diggs' question about [Implementation of standard recycling rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335099/implementation-of-standard-recycling-rules)):

*One nice feature of R which is related to its inherent vectorized nature is the recycling rule described in [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) in Section 2.2.*

> Vectors occurring in the same expression need not all be of the same length. If they are not, the value of the expression is a vector with the same length as the longest vector which occurs in the expression. Shorter vectors in the expression are recycled as often as need be (perhaps fractionally) until they match the length of the longest vector. In particular a constant is simply repeated.

I would agree that recycling is a great feature and it makes life a lot easier. But I know a lot of people who also consider it dangerous, and I see their point: sometimes, it would be nice if R could warn you when, for example, you are trying to add a vector to a matrix, because it is not the most natural thing to do.

My question: is it possible to make R send warnings whenever it recycles?

Currently, R would only warn when `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`. I'd like something that warns in all cases. I have looked into `options` but no luck.

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not confident enough in that to give an answer of no. The recycling code is pretty deep. Also, so many internal things assume it that I would imagine that you would be flooded with warnings from internal uses whenever you did anything.

Comment: @BrianDiggs -- I'm right with you on this one. R's recycling behavior is a pretty characteristic feature of the whole language, and is implemented in many many different pieces of C code, so it's not like there's a single function `"recycle()"`, whose execution you could make trigger warnings (via something like `"trace(recycler)"`. Plus you probably don't really want to be warned every time recycling occurs, since it is used **everywhere** in R.

Comment: @BrianDiggs and Josh-O'Brien, thank you for your inputs; you seem to confirm what I was already leaning towards, that there is no possible way to do what I am asking for. Concerning the risk of being flooded with warnings: yes, it would not be a good idea to run everything in such a mode. One usage I had in mind is during the development of library functions; one could run small tests to see where recycling happens, and check that it was used with good intention.

Comment: this is a very lame solution for this but it can be improved. (if it is the way you want)`y<-function(x){
 if (is.na(a[x]+b[x]))
  print('warning:recycle')
 else
  print('calculated')
  
}; a<-c(1:10);
b<-c(1:6);
i<-c(1:length(a));
p<-sapply(i,function(x){y(x)});
t<-a+b;
res<-cbind(t,p);
`

Comment: I think that unfortunately the answer to your question is "no"; other behaviors in R do have options such as `"warnPartialMatchDollar"` (which warns a lot more in many packages than I would expect CRAN to allow, btw), but nothing in `?options` suggests anything about recycling, length, etc. I wish there were (I also wish recycling was _strictly_ limited to same length or length-1, nothing in between, but I realize the _convenience_ it offers in some situations ... that could just as easily yet more explicitly be done with `rep(.., length.out=)`.)