# changing operator default behavior

Tags: r

The design decisions for default behavior of R are fine-tuned for interactive use, but can result in undesired behavior in large codebases run without much user oversight. I would be interested in finding ways to make the language a bit more strict. I have two basic examples.

**(recycling)** Non-congruent vectors are recycled in arythmetic operations:

```
> x=1:10
> y=1:20
> y=rep(1,20)
> x+y
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Is there a way to make this operation result in an error?

**(conversion)** Conversions occur when updating vectors, sometimes changing the type of the element being updated, sometimes the type of the vector:

```
> x[1] <- 'a'
> x
 [1] "a"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
> x[1] <- 1
> x
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
```

Is there a way to make this operation result in an error?

I believe much of the frustration of new and intermediate users stems from behavior like these (which in turn results in a summary judgdement on the language!). Any pointer to general approaches to address recycling and conversion is very welcome.

Comment: Recycling and conversion are core properties of the language. Both are implemented at the C level. Imho changing this in general would require changing the base source code and rebuilding R. That would be a non-trivial task and can be expected to break many, many other functions. You could, e.g., write `+` methods for some class that test if input is of equal length, but there would be significant performance cost and you seem to have something more general in mind.

Comment: What Roland said is right and you shouldn't mess up with the original functions, but you can create your own similar function without a big loss in performance, for example ````"%+%" <- function(x, y) {stopifnot(length(x) == length(y)) ; `+`(x, y)}```` then you can test it with `x %+% y`

Comment: For recycling you can look at [this question and its comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424976/unconditional-warnings-when-recycling). It Looks like it is impossible to change this basic R feature.

Comment: Note that `(1:5) + 1` also uses recycling. Presumably you wouldn't want an error for that.

Comment: For the situations where a warning would be issued, you can use `options(warn = 2)` to get an error instead. It's not sufficient for your needs but it's a step forward in preventing some problems. See `?warning` for more info.

Comment: Alas, a lot of use cases (including the two above) don't issue warnings.

Answer (score 0):

For the addition. David is right on the point. On sensible code I check this kind of things at the entry of a function or at least at the end:

```
    require(testthat)
    expect_equal(length(out), length (mainEntry))
```

The conversion is also a very sensitive issue. In important code I specify the type in the assignment:

```
    X[1] <- as.numeric("a")
```

Will raise a warning.
You can even define classes preventing conversions using [S4 classes](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/s4Classes.html).

Unfortunately for beginners this might not be the easier to follow but should beginners handle critical code anyway?