# Weird vector filtering in R. Please explain

Tags: r, vector

When running the below commands

```
x <- c(1:10)
x

y <- c(1:35)
y

res <- y [x <= 5]
res
```

The result looks like this:

```
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
[26] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5 11 12 13 14 15 21 22 23 24 25 31 32 33 34 35
```

Could you explain how the numbers 16:20 and 25:30 got filtered out? 
Also refer me to a resource where i can learn more about this.

Comment: It is just recycling the TRUE/FALSE to the length of 'y'

Comment: See here also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424976/unconditional-warnings-when-recycling and here for more technical discussion of what R does - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335099/implementation-of-standard-recycling-rules

Comment: I kind of understand why R would use recycling, but do programmers use recycling? I feel that Recycling exits more due to a loophole in R that it cannot fix, and it provides no benefit to the developers who write software using R. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

The logical vector is getting recycled to the `length` of 'y' as one of them is of `length` greater than the other.  If we `rep`licate, it would give the same output as the OP's case

```
rep(x <= 5, length.out = length(y))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#[23]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

y[rep(x <= 5, length.out = length(y))]
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5 11 12 13 14 15 21 22 23 24 25 31 32 33 34 35

y[x <= 5]
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5 11 12 13 14 15 21 22 23 24 25 31 32 33 34 35
```