# How to add a date to each row for a column in a data frame?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(DAY = character(), ID = character())
```

I'm running a `(for i in DAYS[i])` and get IDs for each day  and storing them in a data frame

```
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(ID = IDs))
```

I want to add the `DAY[i]` in a second column across each row in a loop.
How do I do that?

Comment: It is not the correct way to create a data.frame. Better to run your loop and create vector inside the loop. Then after the loop, create the data.frame from the different vectors.

Comment: You don't' need any loop. R isn't Java. Please show us `DAY` and how the desired result should look like.

Comment: Input : ID                 Day1           Day2
Output : ID DAY where DAY is between Day1 and Day2

Answer (score 1):

As @Pascal says, this isn't the best way to create a data frame in R. R is a vectorised language, so generally you don't need `for` loops.

I'm assuming each ID is unique, so you can create a vector of IDs from 1 to 10:

```
ID <- 1:10
```

Then, you need a vector for your `DAY`s which can be the same length as your IDs, or can be [recycled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335099/implementation-of-standard-recycling-rules) (i.e. if you only have a certain number of days that are repeated in the same order you can have a smaller vector that's reused). Use `c()` to create a vector with more than one value:

```
DAY <- c(1, 2, 9, 4, 4)
df <- data.frame(ID, DAY)
df

#    ID DAY
# 1   1   1
# 2   2   2
# 3   3   9
# 4   4   4
# 5   5   4
# 6   6   1
# 7   7   2
# 8   8   9
# 9   9   4
# 10 10   4
```

Or with a vector for `DAY` that includes unique values:

```
DAY <- sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(ID, DAY)
df
#     ID DAY
#  1   1  61
#  2   2  30
#  3   3  32
#  4   4  97
#  5   5  32
#  6   6  74
#  7   7  97
#  8   8  73
#  9   9  16
#  10 10  98
```