# %in% vs == for subsetting

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I am getting some unexpected behavior using %in% c() versus == c() to filter data on multiple conditions. I am returning incomplete results when the == c() method. Is there a logical explanation for this behavior?

```
df <- data.frame(region = as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)),
             value = 1:10)

library(dplyr)   
filter(df, region == c(1,2))
filter(df, region %in% c(1,2))

# using base syntax
df[df$region == c(1,2),]
df[df$region %in% c(1,2),]
```

The results do not change if I convert 'region' to numeric.

Comment: `c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)==1:2` is `c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)==c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)`, or what do you mean?

Comment: Needs to be written as `region == 1 | region == 2`. Above comment refers to R's (sometimes annoying) vector recycling rule.

Comment: using data.table will make this work as (I think) you expect it to i.e. return an error for `df[region == c(1,2)]`

Comment: region == 1 | region == 2 works fine, as does %in% c(1,2). Still not sure why == c(1,2) returns incomplete results. lukeA, not sure what you are asking, but my example is supposed to return rows where region is either a 1 or a 2.

Comment: `==` is really made for vectors of equal length, but then R recycles (which is sometimes very useful!). For example `c(1, 2) == c(2, 1)` of course returns `FALSE FALSE`. It's checking the elements pairwise: are the first elements equal?, are the second elements equal?, etc. If you want set membership, then `%in%` is the correct choice, and `c(1, 2) %in% `c(2, 1)` are both `TRUE`.

Answer (score 4):

> I am returning incomplete results when the == c() method. Is there a
>   logical explanation for this behavior?

That's kind of logical, let's see:

```
df$region == 1:2
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 df$region %in% 1:2
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The reason is in the first form your trying to compare different lenght vectors, as @lukeA said in his comment this form is the same as (see [implementation-of-standard-recycling-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335099/implementation-of-standard-recycling-rules)):

```
# 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4  ## df$region
# 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2  ## c(1,2) recycled to the same length
# T F T T F F F F F F  ## equality of the corresponding elements

df$region == c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Where each value on the left hand side of the operator is tested with the corresponding value on the right hand side of the operator.

However when you use `df$region %in% 1:2` it's more in the idea:

```
sapply(df$region, function(x) { any(x==1:2) })
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I mean each value is tested against the second vector and TRUE is returned if there's one match.

Comment: In my opinion 5.4.1 of the R intro is the best reference (linked from the Docs here:  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/5649/recycling#t=201609121720574317665&a=remarks )