# Preserve mask length when subsetting in R

Tags: r, vector, mask

Why in R masking doesn't fix the length? That is

```
> v=c(1,2,3,4,5)
> mask=c(T,T,T,T)
> v[mask]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Instead of

```
> v[mask]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335099/implementation-of-standard-recycling-rules R recycle the smaller vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of recycling. If vectors are of different lengths, the shorter vector is recycled in the order it is specified.

Compare the following:

```
> mask=c(F)
> v[mask]
numeric(0)

> mask=c(T)
> v[mask]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

> mask=c(T, F, T, F)
> v[mask]
[1] 1 3 5
```

In the first example, `F` is recycled 5 times, so no values are printed - the opposite happens in the second example.

In the third example 2 and 4 are omitted because they are indexed with `F`, but the mask is recycled to give a `T` for element 5

**Edit**
The desired result being 1, 2, 3, 4?
Try mask <- c(T, T, T, T, F)

This is what allows statement like

```
v[v != 5]
```

Because that comparison is recycled over the whole vector

Comment: Ok, but how do I get the desired result?

Comment: mask = c(T,T,T,T,F)

Comment: Is there a more general solution? Because mask can actually vary, so I cannot just drop the last element.

Comment: The last example is general. You can index using any comparison you like. ie from a vector or you can write a function that will make any / as many comparison you like

Comment: Not really. If say I now have `v=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)` and `mask=c(T,T,T)` your solutions gives me `1 2 3 4 6` instead of `1 2 3`

Comment: Yes, because it selects anything not equal to 5. It was an example for how you customize you index to suit the outcome you want. If you only ever want to find numbers 1-4 then `v[v <= 4]` or for odd numbers `v[v %% 2 != 0].  What I mean is that 'mask <- ` whatever condition you wish to satisfy
` etc, etc

Comment: Yes I guess that by using `length` I can get the desired behavior. Thanks for the suggestion