# What does specifying a vector of means/standard deviations for rnorm do?

Tags: r

The following line produces 1000 random draws from the normal distribution with mean 0 and sd 1.

```
rnorm(1000,0,1)
## [1] -0.3314116  2.3704895 -0.8110266  1.0777301 -0.8812868  0.3292315
```

The following line also produces 1000 draws, but now the mean varies between 0 and 100 for each observation.

```
rnorm(1000,c(0,100),1)
## [1]  -1.12269954  98.83932359   0.07735428  99.91774166   0.60986243 101.50529435
```

So what happens in this case? What is the general logic?

```
rnorm(1000,c(0,100),c(1,10))
```

Thank you for the link to vector recycling, that is one piece I was missing. Another is *which* combination of means and standard deviation are used. For example, does

```
rnorm(1000,c(0,100),c(1,10))
```

ever draw from the normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 10? The below answer addresses this.

Comment: What is happening is vector recycling; `rnorm` can produce vectors of variates from normal distributions. The length of the result is specified by the first argument, all other arguments are recycled in the usual R way. Better asked on stackoverflow or just google this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementation of standard recycling rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335099/implementation-of-standard-recycling-rules), the question linked describes the recycling behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created an example to express the third example in your question.

```
set.seed(1337)
x=rnorm(2000,c(0,100),c(1,10))
even=1:500*2
odd=0:499*2+1
mean(x[odd]) #0.00427
mean(x[even]) #99.5
sd(x[odd]) #1.01
sd(x[even]) #9.49
```

You can see that the function alternates between the first and second input of each vector. As Alex commented, if one of the vectors was a different length than the other (your second example), then the shorter vector would "recycle" the inputs until it is as long as the longer vector. So, `rnorm(1000,c(0,100),1)` is converted to `rnorm(1000,c(0,1000),c(1,1))` by recycling the input of the second vector.

Comment: is such behavior documented somewhere? It's quite mystical otherwise.